# Deny access to any URL containing certain word(s)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Something is continually hammering my website adding PLACEIMPMACROHERE to the end of URLs. I am not sure what it is, but it doesn't look good. So I'd like to thwart it if possible.

'Place IMP Macro Here' as if it's some bot/flooding script and it hasn't been configured yet.

How could I block any URL ending in PLACEIMPMACROHERE, it appears as if it's a folder. It hits like this:

```
www.website.com/directory/another-directory/PLACEIMPMACROHERE
```

Or anywhere, not always the same location, sometimes:

```
www.website.com/directory/PLACEIMPMACROHERE
```

I tried this but with no success

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} PLACEIMPMACROHERE  [NC]  
RewriteRule .*  - [F]
```

Does anyone see where that's going wrong or is it entirely wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with Jon Lin, your mod_rewriting should work, though it could be simplified:

```
RewriteRule PLACEIMPMACROHERE - [F]
```

That said, I'd suggest you use the [FilesMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#filesmatch) directive:

```
<FilesMatch "PLACEIMPMACROHERE$">
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

I believe it's less resource-intensive, and also less complex.

Comment: Hey @SáT, what did you mean less resource intensive. Does sending these requests to forbidden still use resources? This is something I did wonder but was unable to find the answer to, so very interesting you mention it :)

Comment: Forbidding the resource is very cheap, as Apache doesn't even need to check the hard drive to see if the resource exist or anything. What I meant is, mod_rewrite is a huge beast, and as a rule of thumb, we should avoid using it if at all possible. Even the [manual says as much](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/avoid.html). It can do anything (really, mod_rewrite is actually Turing-complete), but it's huge, unwieldy, and the rules can be a nightmare to maintain.

Answer (score 3):

The rule that you have should work, it simply checks for that phrase *anywhere* in the request, and not just at the end. You can do that by adding another character as a check, also make sure that rule is before any other ones you have and is in the htaccess file in your **document root**:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} PLACEIMPMACROHERE($|\ |\?)  [NC]  
RewriteRule .*  - [F]
```

Oh, also make sure you turned on the rewrite engine:

```
RewriteEngine
```

somewhere near the top of your htaccess file.

Comment: Thanks Jon, maybe it was my placement of the rule that meant it didn't work. As you mentioned adding it before others.